# Cannot connect to SSL from outside ubuntu

Tags: docker, nginx

I've got a very strange problem connecting to my newly configured SSL site. This is an Ubuntu VPS hosted on Amazon lightsail.

I have docker container serving port 80 and 443 as you can see here:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
ce7114e8383a        nginx:alpine                                                                    "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   43 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   app_nginx_1
ffe588588a67        registry.gitlab.com/richardvanbergen/richardvanbergen-personal-website:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'npm run…"   43 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                     app_web_1
```

From inside the server I can make a curl request to that container and get a proper response on SSL. I get this same response on port 80.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-13-199:~$ curl -k https://0.0.0.0:443
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
... // rest of served HTML
```

I have temporarily disabled the firewall entirely just to rule it out.

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
ubuntu:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Yet from the outside I cannot access https://www.richardvanbergen.com/ only http://www.richardvanbergen.com/

This is my nginx default configuration so far. It's a reverse proxy to another docker image.

```
upstream node-app {
  server web:9000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name www.richardvanbergen.com;

  ssl_certificate /certbot/live/www.richardvanbergen.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /certbot/live/www.richardvanbergen.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://node-app;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

And this is included by an otherwise default nginx configuration.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  #gzip  on;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Edit #1 - Output from Test-NetConnection

```
C:\Users\Richard> Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName www.richardvanbergen.com -InformationLevel Detailed
WARNING: TCP connect to (3.8.139.86 : 443) failed
WARNING: Ping to 3.8.139.86 failed with status: TimedOut


ComputerName            : www.richardvanbergen.com
RemoteAddress           : 3.8.139.86
RemotePort              : 443
NameResolutionResults   : 3.8.139.86
MatchingIPsecRules      :
NetworkIsolationContext : Internet
IsAdmin                 : False
InterfaceAlias          : WiFi
SourceAddress           : 192.168.1.103
NetRoute (NextHop)      : 192.168.1.1
PingSucceeded           : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT)  : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded        : False

C:\Users\Richard> Test-NetConnection -Port 80 -ComputerName www.richardvanbergen.com -InformationLevel Detailed


ComputerName            : www.richardvanbergen.com
RemoteAddress           : 3.8.139.86
RemotePort              : 80
NameResolutionResults   : 3.8.139.86
MatchingIPsecRules      :
NetworkIsolationContext : Internet
IsAdmin                 : False
InterfaceAlias          : WiFi
SourceAddress           : 192.168.1.103
NetRoute (NextHop)      : 192.168.1.1
TcpTestSucceeded        : True
```

Edit 2 - I've just added a static IP to the instance so  the DNS hasn't updated yet. It's now at 18.130.20.43.

Edit 3 - Output for comments

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-13-199:~$ ss -ltn
State                             Recv-Q                             Send-Q                                                          Local Address:Port                                                         Peer Address:Port
LISTEN                            0                                  128                                                             127.0.0.53%lo:53                                                                0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                            0                                  128                                                                   0.0.0.0:22                                                                0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                            0                                  128                                                                         *:443                                                                     *:*
LISTEN                            0                                  128                                                                         *:9000                                                                    *:*
LISTEN                            0                                  128                                                                         *:80                                                                      *:*
LISTEN                            0                                  128                                                                      [::]:22                                                                   [::]:*
ubuntu@ip-172-26-13-199:~$ sudo iptables -L -v -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 51 packets, 3040 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
2827  153K DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 100 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 11 packets, 1167 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 107 packets, 6591 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !br-3798a755f648  192.168.16.0/20      0.0.0.0/0
    4   268 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !br-4d6ce8dde9c7  172.28.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !br-71c62a74438c  172.23.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !br-a694dba80b9b  192.168.208.0/20     0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !br-b056a255c235  172.27.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
  388 24669 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.16.2         192.168.16.2         tcp dpt:9000
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.16.3         192.168.16.3         tcp dpt:443
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.16.3         192.168.16.3         tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br-3798a755f648 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br-4d6ce8dde9c7 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br-71c62a74438c *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br-a694dba80b9b *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br-b056a255c235 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !br-3798a755f648 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9000 to:192.168.16.2:9000
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !br-3798a755f648 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:192.168.16.3:443
  47  2484 DNAT       tcp  --  !br-3798a755f648 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.16.3:80
```

Comment: Could you share what error you're facing from the outside world and the command you're using to test?

Comment: I was just visiting in the browser and watching it time out but for the sake of completeness I've added output of `Test-NetConnection` from my home PC.

Comment: Can you comment out the `listen 80;` and retest with HTTPS, please?

Comment: Same deal. Only now port 80 doesn't connect.

Comment: That's very strange. Is the instance attached to Load Balancer?  ALB/NLB?

Comment: Nope, domain points directly to the hosted instance.

Comment: What about Security Groups and NACLs? Are they allowing incoming traffic over HTTPS?

Comment: After starting the containers, can you confirm that 1. there are listening sockets on 80 and 443 (ss -ltn) and 2. docker created the forwarding rules needed for the host mapping (iptables -L -v -n -t nat)?

Comment: Timeout error sounds like a firewall issue to me, check security groups are ok in aws

Comment: @whites11 It's a lightsail instance, not ec2 I don't think it has security groups. Though I could be wrong as I'm new to AWS.

Comment: @ThomasMaier - Added to the post. Like I said though I disabled the firewall entirely via `ufw`.

Comment: Most things can host websites on AWS uses a VPC that mean it uses Security Group(s) Network and ALC rules just like if you're hosting this yourself with actual networking gear. So check under VPC you should have at least One VPC and Security groups and NACL to go with it.

Comment: Thanks for all you help guys, the issue is sorted and it was really simple. See the answer.

Comment: @RichardVanbergen Docker still creates DNAT rules using iptables to forward the traffic to the containers.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is gone now, thanks for the help guys. There's an additional firewall on lightsail under your instance settings. You have to configure the network there.

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail